# String a, b: if(a.equals(b)), if(Objects.equals(a, b)) or if(a..hashCode()==b.hashCode())?

Tags: java, android

What is better for Strings (`String a; String b;`): `if(Objects.equals(a, b))` or `if(a.hashCode()==b.hashCode())`?

I used `if(Objects.equals(a, b))` for Android API >= 19 and `if(a.hashCode()==b.hashCode())` for Android API < 19, but I don't remember why...

Comment: Well, you should never use a.hashCode == b.hashCode as hashcode of two different  strings can be same. Also you need to check both overridden methods ,I.e. equals() and hashcode()., in string class before and after api 19  to figure this out. One of the reason could be your string might have been really large and to decrease the time taken in comparison you used a.hashcode == b.hashcode

Comment: I have no idea why you think API v19 means something special here.  The definition of equals and hashcode hav been set since Java was made in the mid-90s.

Comment: "What is better for Strings" depends entirely upon what you are trying to do with the strings. If you are trying to see if they represent the same value, `equals` (of either flavour) is correct; if you are trying to see if they represent strings with the same hashcode, `hashCode` is correct.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I used `if(Objects.equals(a, b))` instead of `if(a.equals(b))` because inspection

> 'String.equals()' called in internationalized context Reports any call
>   of **equals()**, **equalsIgnoreCase()**, **compareTo()** or **compareToIgnoreCase()**
>   on **String** objects. Such calls are usually incorrect in an
>   internationalized environment.

I used `if(a.hashCode()==b.hashCode())` for API < 19 instead of `if(Objects.equals(a, b))` because inspection

> Call requires API level 19 (current min is 14):
>   java.util.Objects#equals

Comment: Do you know how `Objects.equals(a, b)` is implemented? There's no magic to it: provided the arguments aren't null (which they can't be, if you're planning to invoke `hashCode` on them instead), it's the same as invoking `a.equals(b)`.

Answer (score 3):

As you can read [by checking the class Object documentation here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()),

> It is not required that if two objects are unequal according to the equals(java.lang.Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce distinct integer results. However, the programmer should be aware that producing distinct integer results for unequal objects may improve the performance of hash tables.

This means that even if a.hashCode() == b.hashCode() is true, it doesn't necessarily mean that a.equals(b) is true.

For object comparison, you should always rely on the equals method. This is true for any kind of Object, unless you have some very special need, and not only for Strings.

Edit: as pointed out in the comments,

> hashCode can return the same for two totally different types of objects

Comment: What about any Android API doc/inspections link? Where I can read about difference for API<19?

Comment: Both equals and hashCode methods are defined in the class Object since the very first version of the Java language. I can't imagine why it should be different for API<19 and API>=19. You should have no problem using equals on API<19 :)

Comment: You should use different methods (or in general, different code) only if you want to access new API features but you also want to support older Android versions. Android uses Java, and equals and hashCode are available since Java 1 and since Android API 1, so both must be accessible: you are not talking about a new feature of the Java language or a new feature of the Android API, but of a basic feature of Java. Hope this is more clear.

Comment: More than that-  hashCode can return the same for two totally different types of objects.  I can have an Integer and a String that hash to the same value.  If you want to test equality, always use equals.

Comment: @Raffolox I edited question and post my answer below

Comment: Check the documentation for the method equals of the class Objects: the equality test is performed using the equals method, it's the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

It is more truthful (both semantically and convention perspective) that you use Equals. No need take take action extra. As you can in source code of equals it is possible to comparing objects are same.

```
public boolean equals(Object anObject) {
    if (this == anObject) {
        return true;
    }
    if (anObject instanceof String) {
        String anotherString = (String)anObject;
        int n = count;
        if (n == anotherString.count) {
            char v1[] = value;
            char v2[] = anotherString.value;
            int i = offset;
            int j = anotherString.offset;
            while (n-- != 0) {
                if (v1[i++] != v2[j++])
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

String has its own version of **equals()** and **equalsIgnoreCase()**. use them,

Answer (score -1):

It states in the [Javadoc for `Object.hashCode`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode--):

> This method is supported for the benefit of hash tables such as those provided by HashMap.

If you aren't building a hash table, using `hashCode` is almost certainly not the right method to be using.

---

You haven't actually described what you are trying to do, but `Objects.equals(a, b)` and `a.hashCode() == b.hashCode()` are not substitutable.

For example, `Objects.equals("AA", "Ab")` is false, but `"AA".hashCode() == "Ab".hashCode()` is true.